# Yii2: Replace default confirmation message used by Gridview with Sweet alert

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, sweetalert

I am using [yii2mod/yii2-sweet-alert](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-sweet-alert) in my projects, I am using it on basic and advanced themes, and I love it.

**The question.**
How can I change the grid default confirmation dialog that is a plain javascript confirmation in order to use [Sweet-alert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) to make it look better?

I already tried modifying the button's template for the delete, because if you want to change the message you will do the following:

```
        [
            'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
            'template' => '{update}{delete}',
            'buttons' => [
                'delete' => function($url, $model){
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
                        'class' => '',
                        'data' => [
                            'confirm' => 'Are you absolutely sure ? You will lose all the information about this user with this action.',
                            'method' => 'post',
                        ],
                    ]);
                }
            ]
        ]
```

But I haven't been successful on changing the confirmation message from the javascript one to sweet alert.

---

Also I am trying as a second option, to make it work with [Krajee/ Grid and actionColumn](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#action-column) but still can make it work «this is the second option am working, to do this».

```
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'viewOptions' => ['hidden' => true],
            'updateOptions' => ['title' => 'Edit events', 'data-toggle' => '??'],
            'deleteOptions' => ['title' => 'delete your event', 'data-toggle' => 'I am Lost here'],
        ],
```

[image: from classic to sweet alert]

Please any idea on how to change this behavior?

---

**MORE ON HOW TO SOLVE IT** - *thanks to* [**`@muhammad-omer-aslam`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731614/muhammad-omer-aslam)

1. create a js file on your public folder, in my case
   **`/backend/web/js/confirmSwal.js`** and add the provided code:

   Add these lines

   ```
   yii.confirm = function (message, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
       swal({
           title: message,
           type: 'warning',
           showCancelButton: true,
           closeOnConfirm: true,
           allowOutsideClick: true
       }, okCallback);
   };
   ```
2. Add this to your AppAssets on

   `/backend/assets/AppAssets.php`

   ```
   public $js = [
       '/js/confirmSwal.js',
   ];
   ```
3. And that's it it works beautiful.

[image]

Thanks again to Muhammad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE2**

Just correction in the code you need to do

- `okCallback.call()` or add parenthesis `()` like 'okCallback()`
- and then `cancelCallback.call()` or add parenthesis `cancelCallback()`

inside the `.then((selection)=>{})` and it is an anonymous function and needs to be called rather than just using `okCallback` so the code inside the `.then((selection)=>{})` becomes

```
if(selection){ okCallback.call();}else{ cancelCallback.call();}
```

**UPDATE**

The following options are deprecated in `sweetalert 2.0` version,

- `callback` in favor of `promise`:
  If the user clicks the confirm button, the promise resolves to `true`. If the alert is dismissed (by clicking outside of it), the promise resolves to `null`.
- `allowClickOutside` is now `closeOnClickOutside` for clarity.
- `showCancelButton` and `showConfirmButton` are no longer needed. Instead, you can set `buttons: true` to show both buttons or `buttons: false` to hide all buttons. By default, only the confirm button is shown.
- When using a single string parameter (e.g. `swal("Hello world!")`), that parameter will be the modal's `text` instead of its `title`.
- `type` and `imageUrl` have been replaced with a single `icon` option. If you're using the shorthand version (`swal("Hi", "Hello world", "warning")`) you don't have to change anything.

So you can change the code to the following in case you are using ver `2.x` or upgrading from `1.x`.

```
yii.confirm = function (message, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    swal({
            text: message,
            icon: 'warning',
            buttons : {
                cancel : {
                    text : "Oops! No",
                    value : null,
                    visible : true,
                    className : "",
                    closeModal : true
                },
                confirm : {
                    text : "Delete It Already",
                    value : true,
                    visible : true,
                    className : "",
                    closeModal : true
                }
            },
            closeOnClickOutside: true
    }).then((selection) => {
     if(selection){okCallback;}else{cancelCallback;}
    });
}
```

---

You can override the Yii2 default `data-confirm` popup with the following code:

The basics are to include the asset, then add this JS:

```
/**
 * Override the default yii confirm dialog. This function is
 * called by yii when a confirmation is requested.
 *
 * @param message the message to display
 * @param okCallback triggered when confirmation is true
 * @param cancelCallback callback triggered when canceled
 */
yii.confirm = function (message, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    swal({
        title: message,
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        allowOutsideClick: true
    }, okCallback);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. it works beautiful.
I will extend your solution on my question.