# Yii2 PJAX delete button outside of GridView

Tags: yii2, pjax

In my Yii2 app I have a `view` (item/view) that shows images (`Image` model) that belong to that `Item`. It's a PHP/HTML page, no Yii2 widgets (`GridView`, `DetailView`, etc). I want to have a delete button below the image that will use the delete method on the `ImageController`.

Is there a built in way to create a delete button that will have a confirmation dialog and handle the pjax like `GridView` does? Or will I have to roll my own?

Comment: not clear if you are asking about a `DetailView` widget or `GridView` where you are displaying the image and want a button, or you dont have any of them and just want a button in a simple view that should act the same as a default `delete` button in the `view.php` file that is generated by the `CRUD` which asks for a confirmation before delete.

Comment: adding your view code or an image which describes the situation would help

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I updated my question. I don't have any widgets, just a plain view right now. I want to know if there's a built in way to replicate the gridview delete functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always use the `data-confirm` attribute to add the delete confirmation like in the grid view, also you should specify the `'method'=>'post'` for the button you are creating see below

```
<?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
            'data' => [
                'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                'method' => 'post',
            ],
        ]) ?>
```

Apart from this if you want to change the default confirmation overall on the site to a more hify confirmation like sweet-alert you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220106/yii2-replace-default-confirmation-message-used-by-gridview-with-sweet-alert/49220391#49220391)

Comment: Perfect! that worked wonderfully. I had no idea about those data attributes. I combined that with Kartik's dialog override and got the exact solution I was looking for, thanks!