# How to disable /override dependencies in Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, assets, sweetalert, kartik-v

**Problem**:

The 'kartik-v\yii2-dialog' which is used by 'kartik-v\tree-manager' overrides Sweetalert dialog/message box.

How does one disable the treeview-manager's dependency 'kartik-v\yii2-dialog' in order to use SweetAlerts?

**Tried**:

```
'assetManager' => ['bundles' => [ 'kartik\dialog\DialogAsset' => ['js' => [],], ... ,
```

Sweetalert starts working in grids and confirm events, but then treemanager no longer works (Uncaught ReferenceError: KrajeeDialog is not defined)

In Pictures:

Have:

[image: Kartik-v\dialog]

Want:

[image: SweetAlert]

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Here is the override code, which has worked, but now kartik\yii2-dialog is loaded afterward and overrides this:

```
yii.confirm = function(message, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
if (message.constructor === Array) {
    swal(
        {
            html: true, // SweetAlert1
            title: message[0],
            text: message[1],
            //html: message[1], // SweetAlert2
            //confirmButtonColor: '#E80000',
            confirmButtonColor: message[3],
            //type: 'warning',
            type: message[2],
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonText: 'Avbryt',
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            allowOutsideClick: true,
            buttonsStyling: false,
        },
        okCallback
    );
} else {
    swal(
        {
            html: true, // SweetAlert1
            title: message,
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonText: 'Avbryt',
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            allowOutsideClick: true,
            buttonsStyling: false,
        },
        okCallback
    );
}
};

confirm = function(message, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    if (message.constructor === Array) {
        swal(
            {
                html: true, // SweetAlert 1
                title: message[0],
                text: message[1],
                //html: message[1], // SweetAlert2
                //confirmButtonColor: '#E80000',
                confirmButtonColor: message[3],
                //type: 'warning',
                type: message[2],
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonText: 'Avbryt',
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                allowOutsideClick: true,
                buttonsStyling: false,
            },
            okCallback
        );
    } else {
        swal(
            {
                html: true, // SweetAlert 1
                title: message,
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                cancelButtonText: 'Avbryt',
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                allowOutsideClick: true,
            },
            okCallback
        );
    }
};

yii.alert = function(message, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    swal(
        {
            title: message,
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: false,
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            buttonsStyling: false,
        },
        okCallback
    );
};

alert = function(message, okCallback, cancelCallback) {
    swal(
        {
            title: message,
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: false,
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            buttonsStyling: false,
        },
        okCallback
    );
};
```

Comment: Which Version of Sweet Alert are you using ? 1 or 2

Comment: Sweet alert 1 thank you @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: i am also using the sweetalert 1 in one of my projects where i am using the TreeView but i am not experiencing what you are saying. can you show your code how are you overriding the default Yii confirm dialog for the gridview

Comment: i am talking about what you are saying here **Sweetalert starts working in grids and confirm events, but then treemanager no longer works (Uncaught ReferenceError: KrajeeDialog is not defined)**, although it is true that treeview shows the default yii2-dialog widgets confirm and not sweetalert, first you need to add your code and also clearify that in the treview it shows you the kartik/yi2-dialog's prompt or you receive the error message ?

Comment: in kartik\dialog\Dialog there are two properties that are relevant: $overrideYiiConfirm and $useNative, but it is not clear how I set those properties globally. The dialog widget is never used directly only indirectly by other widgets.  Have tried:  'dialog' => [
            'class' => '\kartik\dialog\Dialog',
            'useNative' => true,
            'overrideYiiConfirm' => false,
        ],  in config file, but no effect. If the properties are modified in the vendor file then everything works perfectly, but this is not an option. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: The source of the problem seems to come from: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-dialog/issues/28

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189937/discussion-between-aalesund-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: have you tried adding the `'krajeeDialogSettings' => ['overrideYiiConfirm' => true, 'useNative' => true],` inside the `TreeView` widget configurations?

Comment: were you able to solve the problem with the suggested solution or still having problem?

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an option provided as `krajeeDialogSettings` in `TreeView` which controls the `yii2-dialog` via using,

```
'krajeeDialogSettings' => ['overrideYiiConfirm' => true, 'useNative' => true],
```

According to the docs it should work but for me, it didn't worked, and the `yii2-dialog` always overrode the sweetalert confirm, I wanted to rule out the prompt or the yii2-dialog from the treeview and for that removing the dependency is not that straight forward because the calls are nested and integrated in the Treeview script.

So, I had to override the `krajeeDialog.confirm` where i was loading the `TreeView` widget so that whenever the `krajeeDialog.confirm` is called my custom confirm dialog would be called.

Just add the below on the top of the view where you are loading the `TreeView` widget.

```
<?php 

 $js = <<< JS

 krajeeDialog.confirm = function (message, callback) {
    swal({
        title: message,
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        allowOutsideClick: true
    }, callback);
}
JS;
    $this->registerJs($js, yii\web\view::POS_READY);
```

Although i didnt like the dual approach but that was the only one that worked for me, maybe someone else could post a better solution.